# Seeing touch coordinates in firebug event handler

Tags: javascript, console, touch, firebug

I'm using [quo.js](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) to recognise touch events and debug with Firefox.

So I have the following javascript:

```
$$('#quoTiles').on('doubleTap', console.log);
```

Now when I double tap on my div `#quoTiles` I can see a list of everything passed through the event handler in the firebug console. But I can't see any of the useful touch data listed there. For example I know I can do this:

```
$$('#quoTiles').swiping(function(e){
    dragX = e.iniTouch.x;
});
```

But I can't see iniTouch listed there. In particular right now I'm trying to get the coordinates of a tapped point. How do I find this information through Firebug in Firefox on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the logged event. That will switch to the [*DOM* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel), where all properties of the event are listed.

Furthermore you should be able to do something like this to see the x value directly inside the console logs.

```
$$('#quoTiles').on('doubleTap', function (e) { console.log("%o - x: %d, y: %d", e, e.iniTouch.x, e.iniTouch.y); });
```